# Django Return Queryset from Database table by filtering using Dictionary values

Tags: python, django, filter, django-queryset, django-filter

My goal is to return rows from the books table using values sent by a user through a search form. The search form contains multiple fields author, ISBN and title.

*NB: In the code, the author field is a char, but converted to ID based on authors name due to foreign key relation.*

In this code, there's a get request converted to Dictionary and transformed to allow it to query data from the books table.

```
def search(request):

    form = BooksForm()

    if request.method == 'GET':

        # convert get request to dictionary
         book_search = dict(request.GET)
         print("data before cleaning", book_search)

       #get the name from the dictionary get request
         author_name =request.GET['author']
       
        #get the author id from the author table
         author = Author.objects.filter(full_name__contains=author_name).values()

         #get author_id from author queryset
         author_id = author[0]['id']

      #update the dict with the author id to allow search in books models (foreing key)
         book_search['author'] = author_id
         print("data after cleaning",book_search)

         result_set = Book.objects.filter(**book_search)

         print("book search queryset",result_set)
```

Problem:
When I query the books table using the dictionary it returns an empty query set and I want it to return books from in table.
Does anyone have an idea of how I can make the code work?

Comment: Please don't work with `**book_search` for filter: you make it more convenient to expose sensitive data. For example one can forge a request with `author__gender='F'` and thus for example reveal sensitive data (here the gender of an author) that you want to hide. I would advise to work with `django-filters` which makes it convenient to define forms that filter data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please *don't* allow to filter on arbitrary keys. This makes the view sensitive to *request forgery* where a person can for example make a request with `author__gender` as key, and `F` as value, and thus can expose data that you might want to hide.

You can use a library like [**`django-filter`** <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter) to determine how to filter the queryset. Here you can make a filter that looks like:

```
import django_filters

class BookFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    author = django_filters.CharFilter(
        field_name='author__full_name',
        lookup_expr='contains'
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ['isbn']
```

With this filter, it will only use the `author` and `isbn` keys of the `request.GET`, and thus ignore other keys that might want to filter on sensitive data.

You then can use this with:

```
def search(request):
    book_filter = ProductFilter(request.GET)
    print('book search queryset', book_filter.qs)
    return render(request, 'name-of-template.html', {'book_filter': book_filter})
```

In the template you can then use `{{ book_filter.form }}` for a form based on the filter, and `{% for item in book_filter.qs %} … {% endfor %}` to enumerate over the items in the filtered queryset.

Comment: Thanks this makes a lot of sense. My concern arises from UX where I  have converted the author field from ChoiceField to CharField. It is a foreign key in the books table, I want users to search by typing the author's name instead of using the dropdown, how would you approach that?

Comment: @primeape: well here the filter uses a `CharField` (not a `ChoiceField`), so it filters with `author__full_name__contains=...` (see the `field_name` and `lookup_expr`.